# Android-Facebook integration: First user session has no permission

Tags: android, facebook, permissions

I have an Android application that need to be able to update the Facebook status of a user.
I am using this code to request the appropriate permissions:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    final String openPermission = "basic_info";
    final String publishPermission = "publish_actions";

    Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            Log.d("test", "callback session opened " + session.isOpened() + " " + exception);
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Log.d("test", "callback session permissions " + session.getPermissions());
                if (session.getPermissions().contains(publishPermission)) {
                    doUpdateStatus(session, status);
                } else {
                    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(ctx, publishPermission);
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermRequest);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Session session = new Session.Builder(ctx)
        .setApplicationId(APPLICATION_ID)
        .build();

    Session.setActiveSession(session);

    Log.d("test", "session opened " + session.isOpened());
    if (!session.isOpened()) {
        Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(ctx);
        openRequest.setPermissions(new String[]{openPermission});
        session.addCallback(callback);
        session.openForRead(openRequest);
    } else {
        callback.call(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
}
```

This code works fine, except on the very first attempt of a user (when the user never tried any interaction with my application). In this case, `session.getPermissions()` just returns [], even after the `NewPermissionRequest`, which ends in an infinite loop, the program keeping asking for `publish_action` permission.

How can I make it so that the correct permission is given even at first call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to bypass this issue:
I create 2 callbacks, one for the session open request and one for the status update permission request.

In the callback for the status update permission request, if the session does not have the correct permission I simply close it and create a new session.